# Was Big Bang the "START" of time?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, time, universe, big-bang

I know that this question has been repeated a lot. But I still don't understand this concept.
Big bang created matter and space but how could it possibly create time?
If Big bang didn't create time then Big bang must be a "POINT" in time.
Was Big bang the start of time?
Does time have a beginning? if yes, then is time a phenomenon? if no, then is time infinite?(considering real infinite is impossible?)
(Sorry if my question sounds amateurish but every I just didn't get my answer from any article.)

Comment: Dr. Brian Miller, physicist from Duke university says : "BigBang shows that time, matter, space, and energy all started at the same moment in the past" which means before that they weren't, even time.

Comment: Time is that which the clocks show. A clock in physics is any system that can disperse energy from a local reservoir to infinity with a reasonably well defined periodicity or time dependence (like an exponential decay of radioactive nuclei), i.e. time is "created" by inhomogeneous energy density. A slightly wider definition of "time" would also include otherwise homogeneous and isotropic non-equilibrium conditions, like those at the beginning of the big bang. Unless we can identify such a physical clock mechanism, talking about time in the usual sense is problematic.

Comment: The Big Bang didn't create time. Humans did. Time isn't something floating around out there like some mysterious fluid. It's just a concept that we invented to help keep track of other actual things.

Comment: So time IS a phenomenon? since it was created

Comment: Time is a noun. It is not a directly demonstrable noun, which seems to be really really confusing to people for some reason...

Comment: What is north of the north pole? While its true that most points on Earth have a direction we label as north, the north pole itself is a special point that does not admit such a direction. In the same sense, while most points in time have a past, the big bang itself does not have a past.

Comment: Some of the comments and answers in the linked question are misleading. Here are a couple videos from Don Lincoln of FermiLab. [What really happened at the Big Bang?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZdvSJyHvUU), [What happened before the Big Bang?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr6nNvw55C4)